# How can I retrieve a PdfPCell coordinates in iText?

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to draw a circle inside a `PdfPCell`. I have seen examples on how to do this, and I can draw a circle anywhere on the paper. However, all these examples use fixed coordinates and circle radius.

What I want is to put the circle inside the cell, and make it as big as the cell. I am using this code:

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.setPhrase(new Phrase("A"));
table.addCell(cell);

canvas.circle(cell.getLeft(), cell.getBottom(), cell.getWidth() / 2f);
canvas.stroke();
```

However, `cell.getLeft()`, `cell.getBottom()` and `cell.getWidth()` they all return 0, always.

How can I get the position of the cell in the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the PdfPCellEvent (`cell.setCellEvent(...)`) and then `public void cellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rect, PdfContentByte[] canvas)` gives you the exact coordinates of the current cell.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked perfectly.
For anyone looking for something similar, take a look at [this example from iText](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=94) to find out how it is used.